# Static method heritation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a parent class with methods for writing and reading it from the db. The problem is I have a static method which I want to generalise. What is the best practice for doing this? I've came up with some solutions but all don't work with the static method.

Is there a way to force the childobject to implement the abstract method?

Parent Class:

```
public class Data_object  {

    public byte[] toByteArray() throws IOException  {
        return null;
    }
    public static Data_object fromByteArray(byte[] data){
        return null
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class ModelObject extends Data_object {

    public static Data_object fromByteArray(byte[] data){
        ModelObject result = new ModelObject();
        //set data from byte arrray
        return result;
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: why you want your methods to be static in this case ?

Comment: You can't make a static method abstract because when you call it, you need to specify the exact class for the method being called. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Because he doesn't have an instance yet. He's doing some kind of deserialization, where the idea is:

writing: object.write(stream);

reading: object = DataObject.read(stream);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A static method in Java can't be `abstract` and you can't override it. So you can't force a subclass to implement a certain static method.

The only way out is to require the static method by convention (like a note in the accompagnying JavaDoc) and using reflection to ensure at runtime (or at build time), that the subclass implements the required static method.

---

BTW - this is a common "pattern". `Serializable` does not define any methods, but it's documentation mentions three methods:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
   throws IOException
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
   throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
private void readObjectNoData() 
   throws ObjectStreamException;
```

The "object serialization framework" now uses reflection to test, if those methods are implemented by a class and, if yes, invokes those methods.

But I recommend looking for other solutions *before* using this strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods can't be overridden. You can only *hide* superclass methods by defining a method with same name and signature in the subclass, but it's quite confusing and therefore generally not recommended. The original superclass method could be still accessed by, for example, `((SuperClassName) subClassInstance).staticMethod()`.

In your case it's probably better to make the method non-static.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance does not apply to static methods that way. You call a static method on a specific class, like this:

```
MonkeyModelObject.fromByteArray(data)
```

Even when you do this from "inside" a class, you're behind-the-scenes still invoking that specific method on that specific class. So if you "override" a static method, you're just making a new method with the same name in another class (the child class). There's no run-time selection of methods for static methods.

For the specific case that you're working on, it seems like you're doing serialization from/to byte arrays. Perhaps you're serializing messages from a network stream, or something like that? I would recommend the following approach, maybe this pseudocode can inspire you:

```
abstract class Message
{
    void write(stream)
    {
        stream.write(getMessageTypeCode());
        writeParameters(stream);
    }
    abstract int getMessageTypeCode();
    abstract void writeParameters(stream);
    abstract void readParamters(stream);
}
class ChatMessage
{
    String text;
    int getMessageTypeCode() { return 1; }
    void writeParameters(stream)
    {
        stream.write(text);
    }
    void readParameters(stream)
    {
        text = stream.read();
    }
}
class MessageDecoder
{
    Message decode(stream)
    {
        int type = stream.read();
        message = createMessage(type);
        message.readParameters(stream);
        return message;
    }
    Message createMessage(int type)
    {
        if (type == 1)
        {
            return new ChatMessage();
        }
        throw new error;
    }
}
```